# MongoDB - Safeguard against .remove() entire database?

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm using `MongoDB` as my database, and as a first-time back-end developer the ease with which I can delete an entire database/collection really bothers me.

Simply typing `db.collection.remove()` removes all records from that collection!

I know that an effective backup strategy should render this a non-issue, but I occasionally *do* run `.remove()` on some collections, and I'd hate to type in the wrong collection name by accident and (a) have to go through a backup restore, and (b) lose whatever data I had gathered between the backup and the restore, especially as my app gathers a lot of user data.

Is there any 'safeguard' I can set up my database to use, even if it's just a warning/confirmation that says

`"Yo, are you sure you want to remove everything from <collectionname>?` Choose: `Yes/No"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User roles won't fix your problem. If your account has permissions to delete one user, you could accidentally delete them all. If your account has permissions to update an attribute for one user, you could accidentally update all of your users.

There's a simple fix for this however.

**Step 0:** Backup your database. And test your backups regularly. And make sure you get alerted if the backup did not run, or errored. Replica sets are not backups. I know this is obvious, but [evidentally it's not obvious to everybody.](http://hardware.slashdot.org/story/09/01/02/1546214/why-mirroring-is-not-a-backup-solution)

**Step 1:** Write a [web admin](http://www.activeadmin.info/) GUI interface for your database. This it will only take a day or two -- and it should be simple enough that a secretary or intern could use it without fear for your data. (If you think this will take a long time, find a framework with more bells and whistles. Your admin console doesn't even need to be written in the same language as your app.)

**Step 2:** Data migrations (maintenance transformations of your database) should always be run from scripts checked into source control and tested on non-prod beforehand. The script could be as simple as `mongo -e "foo.update(blah)"`, but you should run it as a script to avoid cut-n-paste errors. Ideally, you would even have a checklist for all migrations. (Check that you have a recent backup. Check the database log and system load beforehand. Write a before and after query that will tell you if the migration was successful...)

**Step 3:** You now no longer need to use the production Mongo console. So don't. It's a useful tool for development, but that's only needed on local development databases.

The above-mentioned Roles might be useful for read-only queries. But you can already do that against the non-master replica set member.

**tl;dr:** You can go pretty far using [cowboy admin techniques](http://slashdot.org/topic/datacenter/amazons-christmas-eve-outage-teaches-recovery-lessons/), but eventually you're going to figure out that it's better (and not much more work) to automate everything.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing you can do in the current version to provide this functionality.

In a future version when user defined roles are available you could define a role which allows insert() and update() but not remove() or drop() etc. and therefore make yourself log-in as a different higher-role user, but that's not available in the current (2.4) version.

Comment: Oh, awesome that they plan to build that functionality in! Is there any timeline or is it just a 'maybe' at this point? I'm sure I'm not the only one who's scared shitless of this function!

Comment: it's slated for the next major release https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8580